# Getting latitude and longitude from an address and writing to a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, file-io

I have having some trouble with this one. I'm getting the impression this isn't possible using javascript.

I have a text file formatted like:

```
Street #    STREET  CITY    ST  ZIP
```

all separated by /t, and I would like to convert this address to latitude and longitude coordinates.

So the idea is to read a line from a text file, and write to either than same local file or to a whole new file if that is easier. **I only have to do this once, Just one single pass of converting addresses to latitude and longitude. Will not be in the application just need for my own use a list of latitude and longitude (around 200 addresses to be converted)**

I am not sure if there is anyway to do this without using Google Maps API, but I know I can retrieve the latitude and longitude by:

```
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              var latlong = results[0].geometry.location;
            } else {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
       });
```

So not only do I not know if its even possible to write to a file using js in the browser, but I also know that the function above is run asynchronous and may mess it up that way.

Any idea? If this is doable in another language that will be easier?

Thanks

Comment: You could post your result to a php file and use php to write to a file ?

Comment: Never used php before, sounds like I'll have to give it a go. Any idea on "how to post my result to a php file" from javascript?

Comment: Sure, do you use jquery ?

Comment: I've probably wrote a dozen or so jquery lines in my time so far. I can follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using JQuery

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latlong = results[0].geometry.location;

        $.post('latlong.php', {'latitude': latlong.latitude, 'longitude': latlong.longitude}, function(res) {
            if (!res.success)
            {
                alert('Something went wrong: '+res.error);
            }
        }, 'JSON');

    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Now, **latlong.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude']))
{
    $coordinate = (object) $_POST;
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/myfile.txt';
    $data = 'Latitude: ' . $coordinate->latitude . '\n' .
            'Longitude: ' . $coordinate->longitude;

    if (false !== file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND))
    {
        return json_encode(array(
            'success' => true
        ));
    }

    return json_encode(array(
        'success' => false,
        'error' => 'Unable to write to file.'
    ));
}
```

Untested

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go. Once this is working I would then have to go from .php file to a .txt file?

Comment: No, the php file is writing to your .txt file, as you can see on line 4. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is pointing to the root of your website, so this file will write and append whats in `$data` to `your/website/myfile.txt`. You can change that to whatever you like. If the file does not exist, it will create it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the snippet I use. I took only the needed part but if you need I could provide the rest of code.

```
function codeAddress(obj) {
    var address = obj.parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address, 'partialmatch': true}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            // uncomment next line to center the map
            // map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            // uncomment next line if you want to place a marker 
            // placeMarker(results[0].geometry.location, map, results[0].formatted_address);

            // save latlng and use it later             
            latlng = results[0].geometry.location.toString().replace("\(","").replace("\)","").replace(" ","");         
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

`Tip:` Just to let you know that you cant sent more than ten queries per second. So, if you read addresses from a text file, implement a pause :)

Comment: That part you posted is what i got already, the posting of that result to a text file was the question. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @cs2016 I was cleaning and copy-pasting the code so I didn't see the other answer. Anyhow, glad you solved the issue :)